# .htaccess not every rewriterule works

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^help$ /pages/help/index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^help/search$ /pages/help/search.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^help/support$ /pages/help/support.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^help/bugfixes$ /pages/help/bugfixes.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^help/([a-z0-9-]+)$ /pages/help/category.php?cat_slug=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^help/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)$ /pages/help/article.php?cat_slug=$1&art_id=$2&art_slug=$3 [NC]
```

The **problem** is the following:

When I go to **localhost/help**, it redirects to localhost/C:/server/htdocs, so I don't see the index page. The same happens when i go to **localhost/help/bugfixes**.

The other pages work perfectly! And untill today, /help and /help/bugfixes did also. :/

If I change ^help/bugfixes$ to ^help/bugfix$ (for example), the bugfixes-pages is showed again. If I change ^help$ to ^help/help$ (or any other thing), it also works for the index page.

I have literally no idea what could be wrong. I restarted apache already a couple of times, but still nothing... I didn't changed anything in the file for the last 2 days.

Can someone help me?

Edit: I also didn't changed anything in the php-files index.php and bugfixes.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^help/(.*)$ /pages/help/$1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^help/([^/]+)/?$ /pages/help/category.php?cat_slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^help/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /pages/help/artical.php?cat_slug=$1&art_id=$2&art_slug=$3 [L]
```